# Why do we need the curl and divergence on Maxwell equations?

Tags: electromagnetism, differentiation, maxwell-equations, vector-fields

Is there a particular reason to use curl and divergence on the description of electromagnetic fields? Given boundary conditions, if someone knows the curl and divergence of any field, is it always completely determined?

Comment: What do you mean with "reason"? Have you not seen a derivation of Maxwell's laws?

Comment: By "reason" I mean... how do we know these conditions are necessary and sufficient to describe EM fields?

Comment: tnb, are you asking if (classical) electromagnetic fields are sufficiently described by the theory of vector fields?  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Helmholtz_decomposition

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By "reason" I mean... how do we know these conditions  are necessary and sufficient to describe EM fields?

If we know the divergence and the curl of a vector field then we know everything there is to know about the field.
THIS is called Helmholtz's theorem.
But there is a condition which is,''to solve a differential equation you must also be supplied with appropriate boundary conditions.''

I suggest this website http://farside.ph.utexas.edu/teaching/em/lectures/node37.html

Generally in electrodynamics fields go to zero at infinity as a boundary condition.

Comment: For the original poster: this section really helped me with what I think is the same question: "how is knowing divergence and curl enough to know the field?"  Normally, it would NOT be enough. But in this case, it is, because we know some extra characteristics of the field: those characteristics are described here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Helmholtz_decomposition#Fields_with_prescribed_divergence_and_curl

Answer (score 2):

The electric and magnetic fields are vector quantities. There is a theorem that says that one can determine a vector field completely by specifying its divergence and its curl and its normal component over the boundary. So you need divergence and curl.

Comment: What is that theorem and why do we need the normal component?
reference?

Comment: Called Helmholtz theorem as stated by Paul

Comment: Paul you can consult text books on Mathematical Physics. You can prove that you cannot have two distinct vectors with same div, curl and normal component.